# how to parse jsonobject into two different lists

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

i want to parse latitude in one list and Longitude in another list.
    any idea how to achieve this in android.i am drawing a route on google maps, so i will be needing lat and lng.

```
{
      "userData": [
        {
          "Latitude": "28.597782",
          "Longitude": "77.298256",
          "IotName": "Bus7821",
          "createdAt": "2016-06-10T09:23:07.244Z",
          "updatedAt": "2016-06-10T09:23:07.244Z",
          "id": "575a86fbaf4d65a333c1a1b6"
        },
        {
          "Latitude": "28.598390",
          "Longitude": "77.297952",
          "IotName": "Bus7821",
          "createdAt": "2016-06-10T09:24:04.265Z",
          "updatedAt": "2016-06-10T09:24:04.265Z",
          "id": "575a8734af4d65a333c1a1b7"
        },
        {
          "Latitude": "28.598362",
          "Longitude": "77.297866",
          "IotName": "Bus7821",
          "createdAt": "2016-06-10T09:25:03.522Z",
          "updatedAt": "2016-06-10T09:25:03.522Z",
          "id": "575a876faf4d65a333c1a1b8"
        }
      ]
    }
```

my code snippet

```
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());



                routeMap = parentObject.getJSONArray("userData");
                for (int i=0 ; i<routeMap.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject routes = routeMap.getJSONObject(i);
//                     routeLatitude = routes.get("Latitude");
                }
```

Comment: Use `routes.getString("Latitude");` and `routes.getString("Longitude");` for  latitude and longitude resp.

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

Gson Library is the best way to do this.
Make a class as per your json object.

```
class UserData {
    double Latitude
    double Longitude;
    String IotName;
    Date createdAt;
    Date updatedAt
    String id;
}
```

Now one line of Gson code will do all your work.

```
UserData[] allRoutes = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, UserData[].class);
```

Hope it will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
    routeMap = parentObject.getJSONArray("userData");
                        for (int i=0 ; i<routeMap.length();i++)
                        {
                               JSONObject routes = routeMap.getJSONObject(i);
                               routeLatitude = routes.getString("Latitude");
                               routeLongitude = routes.getString("Longitude");
                               listOne.add(routeLatitude);
                               listTwo.add(routeLongitude);
                        }
```

listOne and listTwo are your two arrayLists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try {
    List<String> lat = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> lon = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourJson);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("userData");
    for( int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String latitude = jsonObject1.getString("Latitude");
        String longitude = jsonObject1.getString("Longitude");
        lat.add(latitude);
        lon.add(longitude);
    }  
    System.out.print(lat + "" + lon);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

A better approach would be to create a POJO like this:

```
public class MyLocation
{
    private String id;
    private String updatedAt;
    private String createdAt;
    private String IotName;
    private String Latitude;
    private String Longitude;

    //other getters and setters here

    public String getLatitude ()
    {
        return Latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude (String Latitude)
    {
        this.Latitude = Latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude ()
    {
        return Longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude (String Longitude)
    {
        this.Longitude = Longitude;
    }
}
```

Now you can just do:

```
MyLocation ml = new MyLocation();
ml.setLatitude(latitude);
ml.setLongitude(longitude);
```

while getting:

```
ml.getLatitude();
ml.getLongitude();
```

Comment: Wouldn't using a class that groups the two variables together be better than independent lists?

Comment: That would be better but the op wants two seperate list i guess